# RSA finding private key D

Tags: rsa, private-key

Im trying to find the private key D in the RSA cryptology. What I already have are the following numbers.

EDIT:

How should it be be done further to calculate the D? I've tried to use the extended euclidian algorithm but I didn't manage to apply it correctly.

Comment: shouldn't it be D*e + t*(p-1)(q-1) = 1 ?

Comment: Im not sure, thats why Im asking if this is correct ;-)

Comment: Also, the question is confusing: The extended Euclidean algorithm will give you both D and t, so... what was your question again?

Comment: That confuses me, lol. I need to find the D, but im not sure how to do this at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what you want is a solution to

d * 1617 + t * 2320 = 1

As you have said before, you need to use extended euclidean algorithm so solve this. I did it with an [online calculator](http://www.mathcelebrity.com/euclidalgo.php) (but it is easy to implement, just go to wikipedia and do it).

This gives me the following result:

d = 33, t = -23